# Django Python redirect after login

Tags: python, html, django, redirect, authentication

I know this questions has been answered is one ore another way, but I still cant figure out how to redirect after a user is logged in. I know Django comes with built in websites, but I need a custom login form, which looks like this(this is the HTML):

```
{% if user.is_authenticated %}
    <!-- Authenticate account menu -->
{% else %}
    <h3>Login</h3>
    <form action="/app/login/" method="post" accept-charset="utf-8">
        <label for="username">Username</label>
        <input type="text" name="username" value="" id="username" />
        <label for="password">Password</label>
        <input type="password" name="password" value="" id="password" />
        <p><input type="submit" value="Login →"></p>
    </form>
{% endif %}
```

My views.py looks like that:

```
from django.http import HttpResponse
from django.shortcuts import render_to_response
from django.template import Context, loader
from django.contrib.auth import authenticate, login
from django.views.generic.simple import *

def index(request):
if request.method == 'POST':
        user = authenticate(username=request.POST['username'],                    password=request.POST['password'])
        if user is not None:
            if user.is_active:
                login(request, user)
                # success
            if request.POST['next']:
                return HttpResponseRedirect(request.POST['next'])
            else:
                return HttpResponseRedirect('/')
        else:
            # disabled account
            return direct_to_template(request, 'inactive_account.html')
    else:
        # invalid login
        return render_to_response("app/index.html")
return render_to_response("app/index.html")
```

I did not write the code myself entirely. I figured out that the redirect happens in the html file some where here: `<form action="/app/login/`. But django says it cant find the url. All in all I have to say I am new to web programming+django+python and not totally clear on the concept.
Thanks for help!!

Comment: You have a missing `)` in `authenticate(username=request.POST['username']`, and your indenting is not correct. Please update your question, and post your `urls.py`.

Answer (score 0):

After `login(request, user)` you need to return some http response, for example it's a page rendered from ome template. But if you want to go to some other page, you can return `HttpResponseRedirect('/needed_url')` and you'll get a request to pointed url.

Also you can point `request.POST['referrer'])` as needed url to go to previous page.

[Django Docs - HttpResponseRedirect](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/request-response/#django.http.HttpResponseRedirect)

P.S. In addition I can say the `<form action="/some/url/" ...` points what address you will go to manage you form data. In case with Django you should have a record in your `urls.py` file like `(r'^some/url/$', some_function)`, which will handle you request with specified function.

Comment: As you can see from the question, he is already returning `HttpResponseRedirect`, so that can't be the problem.

Comment: As the author said he didn't write the code himself entirely, so I thought the problem is where to write the url to go to after logging in.